# Flask button python with user authentification

Tags: python, html, flask, button, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a website that user can join a football party.

I have only managed the users id's and authentication and now need a increment button that user can join the party.
What would I need to do in this situation?

Here my home page:

```
     {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
     <div class="container">
      <h2>Button Pressed: {{ButtonPressed}}</h2>
    <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Join">
     </div>`
```

my route.py:

```
@main.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def button():
    ButtonPressed = 0   
    if request.method == "POST":
        ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed + 1
        return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
        
    return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
```